# JsonUtility.FromJson keeps throwing ArgumentException

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, exception, argumentexception

I am trying to receive data from my backend in my unity project, the data looks like this:

```
{"subjectid":98,"name":"test23","first_name":"test23","date_of_birth":"1998-02-16","age":23}
```

I am using the following line to get the data into an object:

```
PatientBackend patient = JsonUtility.FromJson<PatientBackend>(responseBody);
```

The object looks like this:

```
  using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public class PatientBackend : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int subjectid;
        public string name;
        public string first_name;
        public string date_of_birth;
        public int age;
    
       public PatientBackend(string name, string first_name, string date_of_birth)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.first_name = first_name;
            this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
        }
}
```

But everytime this is called it thows the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize JSON to new instances of type 'PatientBackend.'
  at UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson (System.String json, System.Type type) [0x00056] in <5070e0347dee4c9faba7201166fbed9d>:0 
  at UnityEngine.JsonUtility.FromJson[T] (System.String json) [0x00001] in <5070e0347dee4c9faba7201166fbed9d>:0 
  at DataService+<createPatient>d__8.MoveNext () [0x0021b] in C:\Users\diete\Documents\Stage\bedrijf_CLEAN-CLONE\VRStrokeRehabilitation\Unity\UnityProject\Assets\Scripts\DataService.cs:87 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<createPatient>d__8:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/DataService.cs:90)
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: The exception is not very clear but i think it could be because the `PatientBackend ` does not have an empty constructor

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be the issue. I just made an empty constructor and it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PatientBackend` should not be a MonoBehaviour. The JsonUtility can only be used for data classes. MonoBehaviours are components which need to be attached to gameobjects. You can't simply "create" an instance, that's why it failed.

see [Answers.unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1308015/jsonutility-cannot-deserialize-json-to-new-instanc.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can not create instances of `MonoBehaviour` via the JsonUtility. A `MonoBehaviour` only makes sense if it is attached to a `GameObject`.

It is also not allowed that a `MonoBehaviour` implements a constructor.

---

Either do not make it a `MonoBehaviour` at all. And rather use

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PatientBackend
{
    public int subjectid;
    public string name;
    public string first_name;
    public string date_of_birth;
    public int age;
    
    public PatientBackend(string name, string first_name, string date_of_birth)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
    }
}
```

and

```
var patientBackend = JsonUtility.FromJson<PatientBackend>(jsonString);
```

Or if you really need this as a `MonoBehaviour` instead rather use [`JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html) in order to only overwrite the fields of an existing instance.

```
public class PatientBackend : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int subjectid;
    public string name;
    public string first_name;
    public string date_of_birth;
    public int age;
}
```

and

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(jsonString, existingpatientBackend);
```

Comment: Thanks and I did as Connor Stoop already said. I just made it without making patientBackend a monobehaviour and it worked.